# Changing one state in an array causes a re-rendering of the entire loop-generated custom components in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks. I am populating a list of buttons from a map. Each button has its own state on the `disabled` property. After they were populated, when a button was clicked, I want to set that button to disable.

```
const initialBtnDisabled = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(initialBtnDisabled);

const onChange = event => {
  const btnIndex = event.target.value;

  let btnDisabledcopy = [...btnDisabled]
  btnDisabledcopy[btnIndex] = true
  setBtnDisabled(btnDisabledcopy)        
}

const Button = (props) => {
  console.log("I am from button");

  const { btnIndex } = props
    return (
      <button onClick={onChange} value={btnIndex} disabled={btnDisabled[btnIndex]}>click me</button>
          )
}

const btnArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const btnFields = btnArr.map((item, index) =>
  <td key={index}>
    <Button btnIndex={index} />
  </td>
);

return (
  <tr>{btnFields}</tr>
)
```

Now this works, but the problem is on every button click, the Button component is being re-rendered for the entire loop again, while I was only changing one state of the array. My `console.log` in the `Button` component is logging 8 times on every click.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: just use a scalar disabled state value in the Button component

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent re-rendering using React PureComponent.
This only re-renders the component if the passed props are updated.

```
const initialBtnDisabled = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(initialBtnDisabled);

const onChange = event => {
  const btnIndex = event.target.value;

  let btnDisabledcopy = [...btnDisabled]
  btnDisabledcopy[btnIndex] = true
  setBtnDisabled(btnDisabledcopy)        
}

class Button extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    console.log("I am from button");
    const { btnIndex } = this.props;
    return (
      <button onClick={onChange} value={btnIndex} disabled={btnDisabled[btnIndex]}>click me</button>
    )
  }
}

const btnArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const btnFields = btnArr.map((item, index) =>
  <td key={index}>
    <Button btnIndex={index} />
  </td>
);

return (
  <tr>{btnFields}</tr>
)
```

Comment: This still re-render

Comment: @reddy Is it still logging 8 times on click of one button ?

Comment: Yes, on every button click

Comment: @reddy My Bad, I mentioned in the comment to use PureComponent but I had used React.Component while writing the code. I have updated the code now. I hope this works now :/

Comment: Still the same thing, is it because my btnDisabled state being an array?

Comment: Can you try moving Button Component outside of the current Component's Definition.

Comment: I can't, I have the handler function and props value linking to the button

Comment: Both handler and value can be passed as props if you move the component.

Comment: Still the same thing. It only stop when I commented out the `setBtnDisabled` in the onChange handler

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are re-rendering because their props are changing.

By moving the `Button` definition outside the render function you can achieve this like so:

```js
const Button = memo(props => {
  console.log('I am from button')

  const { btnIndex, onClick, disabled } = props
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => onClick(btnIndex)}
      value={btnIndex}
      disabled={disabled}
    >
      click me
    </button>
  )
})

function App() {
  const initialBtnDisabled = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
  ]
  const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(initialBtnDisabled)
  const btnDisabledRef = useRef(btnDisabled)

  btnDisabledRef.current = btnDisabled

  const onClick = useCallback(btnIndex => {
    let btnDisabledcopy = [...btnDisabledRef.current]
    btnDisabledcopy[btnIndex] = true
    setBtnDisabled(btnDisabledcopy)
  }, [])

  const btnArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  const btnFields = btnArr.map((item, index) => (
    <td key={index}>
      <Button
        btnIndex={index}
        onClick={onClick}
        disabled={btnDisabled[index]}
      />
    </td>
  ))

  return <tr>{btnFields}</tr>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Note the use of `useRef` to track the current value of the state. This allows us to specify `[]` as dependencies

[image: Edit peaceful-pine-wmxwy]